# Entropy in Quantumstatistcs and Seckur-Tetrode-Equation

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, definition, quantum-statistics

In my  lecture we considerd a microcanonical ensemble with $E-\Delta \leq E_{\{n\}} \leq E$ with $E_{\{n\}}$ being the energy-eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian and $\{n\}$ being the quantum numbers. We derived the state-density in an earlier chapter as:

$$\omega_{MK}(E,N,V)= \text{Tr}\biggl(\left[\hat{\delta}(E\hat{1}-\hat{H})\right]\biggr)$$

where N is the Number of particles and V is the Volume. For the derivation of the Sackur-Tetrode-Equation he started by, as he told me, defining the entropy as follows:

$$\omega_{MK}(E,N,V) \cdot \Delta = \text{exp}\left[\dfrac{1}{\text{k}_\text{B}}\text{S}(E,N,V)\right]$$

I asked him afterwards why this is possible and why we do it. He said that since the state-density changes drastically for big N as a function of E it is of advantage to look at the logarithm of $\omega_{MK}$, which makes sense. He also said that it is just a definition of S and that you can write every function as exp-function if I understood correctly.

I am not really satisfied by his explanation and would like to hear why one "defines" the entropy as such and why the second equation is true.

Comment: There are only really two possible answers to the question "why do we define such and such this way?". Either we do it because it is useful or we do it because it matches what we already expect the thing to be. Since you don't seem satisfied with the answer that is useful, what do you expect entropy to be? Not the second equation is basically [Boltzmann's formula for entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann%27s_entropy_formula) is different notation

Comment: Okey, you got me there so let me rephrase my question. What is the physical connection between the state density/number of states and the entropy? I don't see how one would conclude this equation.